# Rails: Test a method that is was called only once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, integration-testing

I know that this maybe really simple, I was wondering how can I test that a method is called only once in rails?

For example I have a model Customer which has a method set_account . I want to know that after some code, it will also run this method but only one time. How can I do that?

I am using rspec.

Comment: Have a look at [RSpec Mocks](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-0/docs/message-expectations/receive-counts#expect-a-message-once).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

at_least_once is the way you do it in Mocha.

I believe with rspec you just add a .once at the end

```
  class Account
      attr_accessor :logger

      def open
          logger.account_opened
       end
  end

  describe Account do
    context "when opened" do
    it "logger#account_opened was called once" do
      logger = double("logger")
      account = Account.new
      account.logger = logger

      logger.should_receive(:account_opened).once

      account.open
    end
  end
end
```

that example is from [here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-13/docs/message-expectations/receive-counts#expect-a-message-once)

Comment: funny i use miniTest and i also had to look it up on how to do it with that

Comment: Thank you, I knew the should_receive method but for some reason it doesn't work. Nevertheless I know that this should work now so I'll check the error somewhere else.

Comment: tail your development.log under /log and see if the problem is somewhere else